# How to notify data set changed of recycler view outside its adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**Description:**

I am saving info with **SharedPreferences** which I use to fill my recycler view with items (My recycler view is in **Activity A**). I am deleting data of shared preferences with a button from an activity in which I don´t have my recycler view (**Activity B**).

**What do I want?**

I need the button to do the following when pressed:

Delete shared preferences data, then go back to **Activity A** (where´s the fragment) and update changes of recycler view.

**Question?**

What´s the code I have to use to notify data changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()`.

Or for better performane if you know positions
`notifyItemRemoved(position)`, `notifyItemChanged(position)`